# FormControl not working Properly in mat-multiselect- Angular Material

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material, form-control

Let's discuss overview of code,
I have binded student-name in multi-checkbox mat-select angular material.I have binded first three student by default checked On initial loading of application so we can able to see three checkbox of student has checked by default.

application  have another condition:  from all list of student, user can select any and only three student and if user trying to select more than three student i am showing alert msg  "Maximum of 3 Student can be selected!"

```
 <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select placeholder="Select Student"
                      [formControl]="studentdropdownsControl" multiple>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let student of studentdropdowns" [value]="student.value"
              (click)="studentdropdown($event,student,studentdropdownsControl)">
              {{student.value}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

```
 studentdropdownsControl = new FormControl();
   selectedstudent =[];
   studentdropdowns = [{value: "Rickey",  id: 0},{value: "JohnSon", id: 1},{value: "Salmon",  id: 2},{value: "vickey", id: 3},{value: "Jony",  id: 4}, {value: "Rock/679",  id: 5},{value: "Batista/641", id: 6},{value: "Sunny/859",  id: 7},{value: "Eliza/1090", id: 8}]

  ngOnit()
  {
    this.getstudentCallsdropdown();
  }


   public async getstudentCallsdropdown(): Promise<void> {

        {
          // Logic to bind by default three student checkbox in dropdown on intial loading 
          this.studentdropdownsControl = new FormControl([this.studentdropdowns[0].value, this.studentdropdowns[1].value, this.studentdropdowns[2].value]);
        }

  }

   public studentdropdown(event: MatOptionSelectionChange, value: string, selectedstudent: any): void {

   //selectedstudent is nothing but value of select and deselect checkbox.
    this.selectedstudent = selectedstudent.id;

     if (this.selectedstudent.length > 3) {
      this.studentdropdownsControl = new FormControl([this.selectedstudent[0], this.selectedstudent[1], 
      this.selectedstudent[2]]);
      alert("Maximum of 3 Studentcan be selected!");
    }
  }
```

[image]

now lets discussed problem  in above image i am trying to select vickey and yes am not able to select. it's perfect !, Condition(if (this.selectedstudent.length > 3)) working fine but now look at below image

[image]

Once we click on Ok of windows alert

[image]

I have selected three student and now when i am trying to select Salmon and here my condition(if (this.selectedstudent.length > 3)) fails and am able to select or mark check to Salmon and interesting thing is it deselect the Vickey automatically.
so by checking with other student I have observed one thing **"from Upside(top) to Downside(bottom) my condition is working fine and its not working Downside(bottom) to upside(top)".**

Why this happening am missing something? or its issue of binding element in array or it's weird behavior of form-control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple ! Just remove those extra selected student from *selectedstudent* array for that you need to find or give index to extra  selected student

```
 public studentdropdown(event: MatOptionSelectionChange,newexstrastudent: string, value: string, selectedstudent: any): void {

   //selectedstudent is nothing but value of select and deselect checkbox.
    this.selectedstudent = selectedstudent.id;
   
     if (this.selectedstudent.length > 3) {
     let selectedstudentindex = this.selectedstudent.findIndex(res => { return res == newexstrastudent });
     this.selectedstudent.splice(selectedstudentindex, 1);
     this.studentdropdownsControl = new FormControl([this.selectedstudent[0], this.selectedstudent[1], 
     this.selectedstudent[2]]);
     alert("Maximum of 3 Studentcan be selected!");
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you select the 3dr student with 4th already selected, it does select it, and then in your function to check if there are max 3 you take the 3 first selected ones.

```
      new FormControl([this.selectedstudent[0], this.selectedstudent[1], this.selectedstudent[2]]);
```

These will be in order from the first to the last, so you will deselect the 4th one and not the one you just selected (3rd one).

---

You shouldn't do it like this, there's no reason to create a new form control each time. You should work with ngModel which will hold a list of the selected items. You can modify ngModel to prevent selecting more. (Careful you need to mutate the array for it to realize it's updated.) See example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sobw4u

```
  change(topping: string): void {
      console.log(this.selectedToppings);
      if(this.selectedToppings.length > 3) {
        this.selectedToppings = this.selectedToppings.filter(e => e !== topping);
      }
  }
```